# Firebase, necesito crear una realtime database con varias colecciones

Tags: javascript, firebase

Hola tengo la siguiente estructura en una realdatabase de firestore.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

resulta que necesito añadir otra "coleccion" osea un  elemento padre que se llame customersWeek, osea es como en sql relacional tener dos tablas separadas y hacer consultas a cada una de ellas por diferentes, es la primera vez que uso este servicio y no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo y sospecho que al parecer eso no es posible. alguna idea porfa ¿?¿?¿?¿?

Comment: Que tal Juan. Usas algún framework o solo javascript puro?

Comment: hola victor, estoy usando VueJS, la verdad estaba muy reacio en usar este servicio porque no lo habia usando nunca, pero el cliente me pidio mucho que le hiciera la aplicacion sin  tener nada que ver con  el backend, es basicamente un CRUD y pense que tal vez era buena idea usar firebase, y aunque me ha aprecido buen servicio no se como separar los datos segun su logica de negocio como se hace habitualmente en sql

Comment: Firebase es un no-sql es una base de datos no relacionada, por lo cual tu negocio lo tendrás que manejar una vez que vas por los datos, Si es un CRUD, es fácil ya que te genera las peticiones básicas GET, POST, PUT, pero si quieres combinar dos tablas seguramente tendrás que hacer una petición y recorrer los datos.

Comment: si Dave ya me di cuenta de eso, me añadi una clave para cada tipo de "tabla", recorri los datos y fui separando segun la clave guardada, gracias muchachos